# Save simple variable in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

this is my issue, when I create a fragment in android for example let's Say:

```
GastosSectionFragment gastosFragment = new GastosSectionFragment();
Fragment.gastosFragment.darUserID(userKey);
```

I send a simple Integer to that activity, no problem. For example lets say I send the number 1. It will be stored in attribute inside that class, because I create the fragment.
Everything will work fine, I receive the number. But when I rotate the phone, the variable "userKEY will be lost, it will converted to cero" I can't save that number when I rotate horizontally my phone, how can I save the data of that variable.

Here I put the code of how I recieve the "userKey" inside the Fragment,

```
public long darUserID(long userKey) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user_id = userKey;
}
```

And the attribute with the onCreate method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_gastos,
            container, false);

    idStatico = darUserID(user_id);
```

And I can't save that little number. this is not a FragmentActivity, this class is just a **FRAGMENT**. First time fine, rotate screen lost the number that I previously recieve. Fragment doesn't have OnSaveBundleInstances.

Comment: I would try storing it within the container activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment can save `user_id` in bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` method and restore after orientation change in `onCreateView` method. Check this [fragment guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), especially in example is shown saving fragment state.

Activity code stays the same (I just changed method name) and your fragment should look like this:

```
    class GastosSectionFragment extends Fragment {

       private static final String BUNDLE_USER_ID = "BUNDLE_USER_ID";

       private long user_id;

       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_gastos, container, false);

         if (savedInstanceState != null)
             user_id = savedInstanceState.getLong(BUNDLE_USER_ID);

         // now is your user_id restored after orientation change, 
         // so you can do some stuff with it            

         return rootView;
      }

      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         outState.putLong(BUNDLE_USER_ID, user_id);
      }

      public long setUserID(long userKey) {
         this.user_id = userKey;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that actually we can do that, after see your answer, is difficult to say this, but this doesn't work for me, but you give the idea. Thank you. I will post how I did to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

add method override, and you variable saving state

Answer (score 0):

After KOSO answer, this is how I solve the problem, hope it helps someone else.

When I create the Fragment for first time everything work well, send the userKey, everything is fine.

```
GastosSectionFragment gastosFragment = new GastosSectionFragment();
Fragment.gastosFragment.darUserID(userKey);
```

Now in order to fix that, a fragment when the phone is rotated, for example to horizontal it will call the override method *OnCreateView()*. Everytime when you rotate the phone this method will be called.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_gastos,
    container, false);
//This is not null when we rotate the screen, first we save the Bundle SavedInstance
//After do that we put a integer, in this case the userKey
//then we recover the user key, and everything will work fine.
if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    savedInstanceState.putInt("userKey", (int) idStatico);
    idStatico = savedInstanceState.getInt("userKey");
}
//this will be null for the first time, only the first time this will bse used.
if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
    idStatico = darUserID(user_id);
}
//Do the rest of the work

}
```